# Pylint: read from stdin?

Tags: python, stdin, pylint

Is there a way to instruct `pylint` to read the input from stdin?

Synopsis string suggests that the file argument is not mandatory:

`pylint [ OPTIONS ] [ <arguments> ]`

But when invoked without a non-option argument, it prints

`Usage:  pylint [options] module_or_package`

And the documentation does not mention stdin anywhere.

This looks non-command-line-stylish...

Comment: So you want to type Python code into `pylint` directly? Why?

Comment: `pylint` is a static code analyzer, it does not consider input and output

Comment: No, there isn't.  But perhaps you could redirect what you would have sent to its stdin to a file before invoking it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I want to run `pylint` on a past revision of the file. In a script which does that, I can checkout that past revision to a temporary location. My question is whether this is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [Pylint 2.4](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.4.html#other-changes) you can supply an extra `--from-stdin` argument to Pylint.

Comment: You also need a name so the full command is `echo $code | pylint --from-stdin anyname`

Comment: Just a minor add on to @SurpriseDog's comment. "anyname" will will be the module name for your script that entered via stdin.  Confirm via `sys.modules[__name__]`.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to do so. You may ask for the feature by creating an issue https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues, or even better, provide a pull request implementing it.

Comment: Someone provided [a PR](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/2746) containing the desired feature. As of [Pylint 2.4](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.4.html#other-changes) you can supply an extra ```--from-stdin``` argument to Pylint. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65780101/2083703)

Answer (score 0):

On linux/unix/OSX you can do

```
pylint [options] /dev/stdin
```

to have pylint read from standard input

Comment: This does not work. Pylint calls `_llseak()` on the file argument, which fails on /dev/stdin.

$ echo 'x' | pylint /dev/stdin
[...]
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek

Comment: Hmmm I'm using pylint 1.4.3 under python 3.4.3 and it works for me.

Comment: Also pylint 1.4.3 under python 2.7.9 works fine so this is not a python 2/3 issue.